# Python def marked as invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, calculator

Im working on a (in-shell) geometry calculator in Python, and I get a syntax error everytime marked as the **def** in the below code:

```
def scepm(r,h):#surface-area circular-prism(cylinder)comment s.o.f. only
    print(3.14159265358979323846264338327950*r**2+3.14159265358979323846264338327950*r*h)
```

It might be something obvious. If it is, can someone please point it out? thanks

Comment: Probably something in the previous line (eg missing paren).

Comment: works for me in console.

Comment: Works for me in the console. Import numpy for including pi as a constant in your code: import numpy as np and the instead 3,14... use np.pi

Answer (score 4):

If the syntax error is indicating the `def` it means that `def` is not valid at this point in the program. `def` starts a statement, so the conclusion would be that you are not starting a statement at the beginning of the line, you must have unclosed parentheses in the previous non-blank, non-comment line.

That is assuming your description is accurate: if not you could get other errors such as an indentation error, or if it indicated somewhere later in the line it could be some other issue you failed to copy exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine you should call the function though:

```
def scepm(r,h): # surface-area circular-prism(cylinder)comment s.o.f. only
    print(3.14159265358979323846264338327950*r**2+3.14159265358979323846264338327950*r*h)

scepm(1,3) #function call
```

Comment: i call the function in the shell. the shell is where the actual calculator is.